# CQRS/EventStore Idempotency?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, neventstore

Implementing/handling idempotency in c# with Jolivers EventStore. Does this mean just taking care of checking an aggregate ID and version alongside the domain/readmodel before handling? Or is there more to it than that?

[EDIT]

The reason I'm asking is that I, for instance, want to develop my app in small feature chunks.

so - imagine I have a dataset of some type with product data for an online store. I want to start developing the app by creating the ability to search for products. this means importing the dataset somehow (doesn't matter how). each product in the dataset eventually fires (for example) a CreateProductCommand - this command goes through the domain which fires the ProductAddedEvent which is then handled by a denormalizer to populate the ProductSearchView

Now - after the search feature is implemented, I want to create the product detail views. I have already ran the import to get the dataset into the system so I want to re-run the events which will fire off the denormalizers to populate the ProductDetailView

Does that make sense?

Comment: Are you talking about not processing the exact same command twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to clean the read model data store and run all the events in the Event Store using the same mechanisms you would use when they were first published.

I am using a separate thing to do this as a step in my deployment process.

Using an instance of the Event Store I get all events from the beginning of time:

```
var commits = eventStore.Advanced.GetFrom(DateTime.MinValue).ToList();
```

Then I iterate over the list and dispatch the events to the read model using much of the same code I use when they are normally dispatched.

That's basically it.

What you should do is to create something that makes this simple for you because you will have to do this a lot.

Comment: i can fire up a new instance of raven, stream to that and then switch i guess?

Comment: this isn't "ideal" tho - replaying the events and not screwing existing data while working on the new stuff would be ideal i guess

Comment: The existing data is in the event store. As long as you keep that intact you can do whatever you want with the read models.

Comment: I new to cqrs world, but this approach looks like to have some drawbacks. Especially on very large application (in term of number of events). Rebuilding the full read model can take a while. A time window when the application won't be available. To workaround this issue, I can see only one solution: duplicate the read model on all front end nodes, instead of keeping only one read model for the farm. Do you think I'm right?

Comment: You can also run the replay on a new separate read model and then switch to that one when it is done. You can keep the system running while you rebuild and when you make the switch you just make sure to also grab the events that you missed since the separate replay started. With that you could come close to no downtime.

Comment: This is a good article on message idempotency. http://blog.jonathanoliver.com/2010/04/idempotency-patterns/